# Inserting Item to Immutable List Attached to Grid Not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, immutable.js

I'm trying to insert a dummy value to an Immutable list which is attached to a Grid.But nothing is showing up when i inspect

```
private filterdSchoolSelectionData: Immutable.List<SchoolSelectionListData> = Immutable.List([]);
   let emptydata: SchoolSelectionListData = {
                    schoolIdentifier: null,
                    schoolName: null,
                    countryID: 1234,
                    countryName: 'asfasf',
                    regionID: null,
                    regionName: null,
                    schoolID: null,
                    isSchoolSelected: true,
                    isCountrySelected: true,
                    isRemoved: false,
                    rowVersion: null
            };
            this.filterdSchoolSelectionData.splice(2, 0, emptydata);
            this.reRender();
```

The size of the list is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main feature of immutablejs is *immutability*. A specific object reference may never change it's data. That is why all functions return a new collection with the result.

So you need to assign the output of your call to `splice` to something, e.g. `this.filterdSchoolSelectionData = this.filterdSchoolSelectionData.splice(2, 0, emptydata);`

Since this one is usually the first pitfall of immutable.js that people step into, I recommend reading the [docs](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/) (or at least the intro) before you  start hating yourself or the library ;-)

PS: That `reRender` looks suspicious. Without knowing the details of your code, if you need to manually trigger rerendering of a component you did it wrong. E.g. not using `props` or `state` for your data. The [] for the List constructor is unnecessary.